# Redirect and balance Java output traffic

Tags: java, c#, redirect, networking, load-balancing

I have a client that make requests to different servers. Sometimes this servers rejects requests from my IP so I need to change it (I have a few public IPs). I also need to change my IP to make geolocalizated request. I'm trying to make a balance server to redirect the client traffic through different server and to keep a log of IPs being rejected. This is what I have in mind:

[image: Balance server]

There would be clients in different networks with different instances of the client. This instances request an output server to the balancer and then all the traffic of clients is redirected through this servers. Output servers could make a connection with the balancer with sockets to say something like "Ey, I'm here. You can use me!". Here I have a silly activity diagram (full of mistakes probably):
[image: Activity diagram]

Is there a simplest way to do this? Maybe I'm reinventing the wheel. If is a good solution, is if possible to do this with Java/C#? How could I redirect the traffic?

Comment: Why do they reject you?  Just fix that.

Comment: API requests. Too many request -> IP rejected. Something like Twitter and their rate limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are reinventing the wheel a little, what your describing is just a load balancer in sticky session/sticky IP mode.

There's a few [open](http://www.apsis.ch/pound/) [source](https://github.com/brunodecarvalho/malabarista) [projects](http://www.linux-vs.org/) [that](http://www.linux-ha.org/) will do what you are looking for. (Each word is a link there)

Personally I'd suggest the [LVS Project](http://www.linux-vs.org/)

Comment: Yep, is a good solution. The problem is that I don't want to force people to spend too much time configuring the server. Also, projects like LVS seems too big for what I need. I'm only talking about redirect the output and keep a log to make decisions. I'm not sure if I can do this with LVS as seems like a transparent process. Anyway, I'll take a deep look to those links. Thanks a lot!